# How to update vcpkg itself?

Tags: vcpkg

I have installed vcpkg, a package manager for C++. Now after some time, I'd like to update it. How can I do that? Do I need to uninstall and reinstall?

Comment: Did you download a zip of the repo or did you clone it?

Comment: I cloned it with git bash

Comment: Did you ask the same question as a issue on vcpkg? https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/15417

Comment: Yes, I did for a better chance of getting an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vcpkg community on Github provided an official answer on their [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/about/faq#how-do-i-update-vcpkg). They suggest pulling the repo and running the bootstrap script.

Answer (score 11):

The best way to update a vcpkg git clone is to do

- save a list of all installed ports somewhere
- `git pull`
- delete the `<vcpkg_root>/installed/` directory
- rerun `bootstrap.bat` or `bootstrap.sh`
- reinstall all ports:triplets you need

Note:

- there is a `vcpkg upgrade/update` command but it is discouraged since it is not transactional
- in general you don't need to run re integrate but sometimes it is necessary `vcpkg integrate remove/install`

Answer (score 3):

Given the previous/sufficient answers, this might be a tad redundant, but I usually go in this order (on my Windows machine)

1. Open PowerShell, go to the vcpkg root directory and run `.\vcpkg --version` to check the version no. You can check the [git](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) to see whether there's a more recent version.
2. To update, stay in the directory and run `git pull https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg`. This runs git fetch to get files from the remote repository and runs git merge to merge the changes.
3. Then run `./bootstrap-vcpkg.bat` to update vcpkg

Answer (score 0):

"git pull"
"./bootstrap-vcpkg.bat"

This downloads current binary of .EXE - but doesn't change your installed packages. No need to delete / reinstall any packages.

You can then "vcpkg update/upgrade" for installed pkgs as you wish.