# gdal header file missing from vcpkg build

Tags: c++, gdal, vcpkg

I use vcpkg as a package manager for a C++ windows GIS application. Gdal is one of the dependencies which I've utilized via vcpkg for a few years now. I recently updated vcpkg in order to update the libraries (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65535604/how-to-update-vcpkg-itself)). Amongst other updates, gdal was updated to version 3.6.3.

However when I attempt to build my application, I get a compiler error saying that the header file "cpl_zlib_header.h" cannot be located. This header file is part of gdal's library. A gdal header file that I include in my code ("cpl_minizip_zip.h") tries to include "cpl_zlib_header.h" and the compiler can't locate it. This missing header file DOES exist in the repository (on [github](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/release/3.6/port/cpl_zlib_header.h)) and is present in the zip file downloaded by vcpkg ([here](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/archive/v3.6.3.tar.gz)). However it is never copied to vcpkg's "Include" path: "vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include" when the package is built locally. So obviously when my build searches the vcpkg include path it can't find it.

I see there is a file called "gdal_3.6.3_x64-windows.list" located in "vcpkg\installed\vcpkg\info" which seems to be a list of all the gdal files built and/or copied to "vcpkg\installed\x64" directory. This list also excludes the header file I require.

Is there some sort of build configuration I need to change to correct this?

Comment: From a quick look it seems like vcpkg added zlib to the default build for gdal in [this commit](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/commit/e6c8c2bc051dc40c39cb4b5b49d180208bdfeda9#diff-306c19cfe05dc8020e1a5027728c4efe1e8333a5fb2798215db7cd7a908021de), building with zlib includes that header, but gdal's CMake doesn't mark that header for installation. I'd file an issue with vcpkg [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues).